# Github Action: how to get Issue Body when [issues: closed]?

Tags: github, github-actions

I know if event_type is issue_comment, you can do like below.

```yaml
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created, edited]

# then, both works

- run: echo ${{ github.event.comment.body }}
- run: echo ${{ github.event.changes.body.from }}
```

However, I would love to get body when event_type is [Issues: closed].

Answer (score 2):

```
on:
  issues:
    types: [closed]

- run: echo ${{ github.event.issue.body }}
```

[GitHub actions documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#issues)

Comment: `body` is not a part of `github.event.issue` even by the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

```
${{ github.event.issue.title }}
${{ github.event.issue.body }}
```

this solved.